Remove unwanted areas texts from a binary image
I want to remove the texts and other unwanted small regions(+ - inside the circle) of a binary image for further processing, as shown in the first image,.
For this preprocessing, i tried this code
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from google.colab import drive

# Mount Google Drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

def preprocess_image(image_path, target_size=(720, 1080)):
    # Load the image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Resize image
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image, target_size)

    # Apply Gaussian Blur to remove noise
    blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized_image, (9, 9), 0)

    # Convert to grayscale
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(blurred_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Thresholding and contour detection to remove small regions
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area < 100000:  # Adjust this value to remove smaller regions
            cv2.drawContours(thresh, [contour], -1, 0, -1)

    # Convert to binary image
    binary_image = cv2.threshold(thresh, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    return resized_image, binary_image

def main():
    # Directory containing images
    folder_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/project/dataset'

    # Get all image paths in the directory
    image_paths = [os.path.join(folder_path, f) for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.jpg')]

    # Iterate through each image
    for image_path in image_paths:
        # Preprocess the image
        original_image, processed_image = preprocess_image(image_path)

        # Display original and processed images side by side
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
        axes[0].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        axes[0].set_title('Original Image')
        axes[0].axis('off')
        axes[1].imshow(processed_image, cmap='gray')
        axes[1].set_title('Processed Image')
        axes[1].axis('off')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

this code is for 50 images inside my drive. Its work very well for the outside texts of the wiring loop as shown in the below image

But I can't solve the issue with inside the wring loop. Such as I want to remove the "2 Ohm" text inside the main wring loop . As a beginner with OpenCV how can i achieve this.

The area threshold you are using is too large. Lower it until the noisy blobs get filtered.

Change cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL to cv2.RETR_LIST to get all contours including internal ones.
